# Creating tooltip for svg linechart using matplotlib

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, linechart

I want to create tooltips (showing data values) for SVG linecharts created using matplotlib. This would enable the user to click or mouseover over each marker in a linechart displaying value of that particular point.

To be able to do this, I need to access marker elements of a Line2D object and add a gid to each such element.

At http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/svg_histogram.html, there is an example of how this is done for an histogram.

```
H = plt.hist([r,r1], label=labels)
containers = H[-1]
hist_patches = {}
for ic, c in enumerate(containers):
    hist_patches['hist_%d'%ic] = []
    for il, element in enumerate(c):
        element.set_gid('hist_%d_patch_%d'%(ic, il))
        hist_patches['hist_%d'%ic].append('hist_%d_patch_%d'%(ic,il))
```

However, if I try doing this using a linechart I find that Line2D object is not iterable -- probably because it is not a collection of patches like histogram bars.

```
H = plt.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,4,9,16], 'ro')
containers = H[-1]
enumerate(containers)
```

This results in: "TypeError: 'Line2D' object is not iterable"

The question is how to access individual markers from a Line2D

There are some recipes to do this using interactive backends of matplotlib. But I need to implement this for non-interactive SVG.

Comment: Try iterating over the `x` and `y` vectors you passed to `plot` (or over `zip(x,y)`) .  Those are the points you want to add gids to anyway, yes?

Comment: I know this can done on an interactive matplotlib plot. How to do this in SVG? Can you point to an example?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/svg_tooltip_sgskip.html

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code in OPs [linked code snippet](http://%20http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/svg_histogram.html)

This works for me at least. However, I haven't found a way to distinguee individual markers

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import BytesIO

plt.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'
_ , ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))

Rand_Values = []
Rand_Values.append(np.random.rand(20)) 
Rand_Values.append(np.random.rand(20)) 
x_axis = range(20)

for i in range(2):
    H = ax.plot(x_axis, Rand_Values[i] , label= "data set %i" % (i+1))  
    ThisContainer = H[-1]                                     
    ThisContainer.set_gid('hist_%i' % i )

plt.xlabel("x-axis label") 
plt.ylabel("random data") 
plt.title( "Interactive chart" )  

leg = ax.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), ncol=1, fancybox=True, shadow=True)

for i, t in enumerate(leg.get_texts()):
    t.set_gid('leg_text_%d' % i)

# Save SVG in a fake file object.
f = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(f, format="svg")

# Create XML tree from the SVG file.
ET.register_namespace("", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
tree, xmlid = ET.XMLID(f.getvalue())

# --- Add interactivity ---
# Add attributes to the text objects.
for i, t in enumerate(leg.get_texts()):
    el = xmlid['leg_text_%d' % i]
    el.set('cursor', 'pointer')
    el.set('onclick', "toggle_hist(this)")

# Create script defining the function `toggle_hist`.
script = """
<script type="text/ecmascript">
<![CDATA[

function toggle(oid, attribute, values) {
    /* Toggle the style attribute of an object between two values.

    Parameters
    ----------
    oid : str
      Object identifier.
    attribute : str
      Name of style attribute.
    values : [on state, off state]
      The two values that are switched between.
    */
    var obj = document.getElementById(oid);
    var a = obj.style[attribute];

    a = (a == values[0] || a == "") ? values[1] : values[0];
    obj.style[attribute] = a;
    }

function toggle_hist(obj) {
    var num = obj.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    toggle( 'leg_text_' + num, 'opacity', [1, 0.5]);
    toggle( 'hist_'+ num  , 'opacity', [1,0]);
    }
]]>
</script>
""" 

# Add a transition effect
css = tree.getchildren()[0][0]

css.text = css.text + "g {-webkit-transition:opacity 0.4s ease-out;" + \
    "-moz-transition:opacity 0.4s ease-out;}"


# Insert the script and save to file.
tree.insert(0, ET.XML(script))

ET.ElementTree(tree).write("svg_lineChart.svg")
```

Answer (score -2):

A better solution for your problem might be the [Charts](https://github.com/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts) library. It enables you to use the excellent [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com) javascript library to make beautiful and interactive plots. Highcharts uses the HTML `svg` tag.

By default all charts will have interactive tooltips!

*Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the library.*